# Помогите с задачей на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Решаю задачу на Python. При вводе `3, aba caba, aba daba, baa cdaa`, выдает ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти причину своей ошибки. Буду благодарен, если поможете!

Вот задача:

> Александр работает на таможне в космопорте. Однажды туда прибыл
> космический корабль после экспедиции на Марс. Сканер в порту забил
> тревогу, на корабле находится ровно один марсианин, который
> замаскировался под члена экипажа. К сожалению сканер не способен
> показать, кто конкретно является марсианином.
>
> Тогда Александр решил запросить протокол общения всех членов экипажа.
> Известно, что в языке реальных членов экипажа вероятность появления
> каждого символа зависит от предыдущего. Однако, марсианин этого не
> знал и пытался пародировать язык реальных членов экипажа, выбирая
> буквы независимо от предыдущих.
>
> Помогите Александру определить, кто из членов экипажа на самом деле
> является марсианином. Гарантируется, что с имеющимся протоколом
> общения это реально сделать.

**Формат входных данных**

Первая строка содержит натуральное число `N (3 ≤ N ≤ 10)` — число членов экипажа на корабле (включая замаскированного марсианина).

Следующие `N` строк содержат текст высказывания соответствующих членов экипажа.
Каждая строка состоит только из маленьких латинских букв и пробелов. Сумма длин всех строк не превышает `104`.
Формат выходных данных
Выведите одно натуральное число — номер строки, которая соответствует тексту высказывания замаскированного марсианина.

**Пример 1**

**Входные данные:**

```
3
aba caba 
aba daba
baa cdaa
```

**Выходные данные:**

```
3
```

А вот мой код:

```py
def find_martian_crew_member():
    N = int(input())
    crew_statements = []
    
    # Чтение высказываний экипажа
    for _ in range(N):
        statement = input()
        crew_statements.append(statement)
    
    # Создание списка вероятностей для символов
    char_probabilities = [0] * 26
    
    # Подсчет вероятностей каждого символа
    for statement in crew_statements:
        for char in statement:
            char_probabilities[ord(char) - ord('a')] += 1
    
    # Создание списка разниц вероятностей
    differences = []
    for statement in crew_statements:
        statement_difference = 0
        for char in statement:
            statement_difference += char_probabilities[ord(char) - ord('a')]
        differences.append(statement_difference)
    
    # Нахождение индекса высказывания с наименьшей суммой разниц
    min_difference_index = differences.index(min(differences))
    
    return min_difference_index + 1


# Вызов функции и вывод результата
print(find_martian_crew_member())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается именно ошибки, то она заключается в том, что происходит выход за пределы массив на строчке:

```py
char_probabilities[ord(char) - ord('a')] += 1
```

И происходит она тогда, когда `char = ' '`, т.к. `ord(' ') - ord('a') = -65`.

Можно например вместо массива, использовать словарь. Вот кусок вашего кода с изменениями:

```py
# Создание списка вероятностей для символов
char_probabilities = {}

# Подсчет вероятностей каждого символа
for statement in crew_statements:
    for char in statement:
        char_probabilities[char] = char_probabilities.get(char, 0) + 1
        
# Создание списка разниц вероятностей
differences = []
for statement in crew_statements:
    statement_difference = 0
    for char in statement:
        statement_difference += char_probabilities[char]
    differences.append(statement_difference)
```

---

Весь код с изменениями:

```py
def find_martian_crew_member():
    N = int(input())
    crew_statements = []
    
    # Чтение высказываний экипажа
    for _ in range(N):
        statement = input()
        crew_statements.append(statement)
    
    # Создание списка вероятностей для символов
    char_probabilities = {}
    
    # Подсчет вероятностей каждого символа
    for statement in crew_statements:
        for char in statement:
            char_probabilities[char] = char_probabilities.get(char, 0) + 1
            
    # Создание списка разниц вероятностей
    differences = []
    for statement in crew_statements:
        statement_difference = 0
        for char in statement:
            statement_difference += char_probabilities[char]
        differences.append(statement_difference)
    
    # Нахождение индекса высказывания с наименьшей суммой разниц
    min_difference_index = differences.index(min(differences))
    
    return min_difference_index + 1


# Вызов функции и вывод результата
print(find_martian_crew_member())
```

Comment: Нет, твой совет не смог помочь мне

Comment: Я не смог решить задачу

Comment: @Nymos ошибка вылетает или что? Поподробней можно как-то?

Comment: ERROR!
File "<string>", line 25
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: @Nymos ... вы серьезно? 1) Верните свой вопрос в исходное состояние. Не нужно из ответа переносить код в вопрос. Тогда зачем мой ответ вообще существует? 2) Я приложил лишь кусок кода, а не весь. Все что вам нужно сделать это взять и вставить этот кусок, на то место где у вас тоже самое происходит.

Comment: Не подскажете, как сделать откад сообщения?

Comment: @Nymos сейчас сам верну. + Добавил весь код в ответ, чтобы вы не напутали ничего.

Comment: прошу простить за мои глупые ошибке, еще плохо разбираюсь в правилах сообщества

Comment: погоди, только что выдало ошибку Код ошибки: WA «Wrong Answer»

Comment: @Nymos а это уже ошибка решения, а не в коде. Ваш вопрос был именно про ошибку в коде) А так, я может и помог бы с решением, но я условия не понимаю и вы видимо тоже, т.к. вы никак не учитываете вот эту информацию: `Известно, что в языке реальных членов экипажа вероятность появления каждого символа зависит от предыдущего`. Меня смущает именно часть с "предыдущая". Вы же в своем коде просто находите того, у кого больше всего не совпадений по количеству букв.

Comment: Значит мне надо, переформулировать ответ, или задать новый, а то лично я зашел в тупик(

Comment: @Nymos Как я писал выше Не нужно менять вопрос, если на предыдущий вам уже дали ответ. Наверно лучше будет если этот вопрос вы вернете в то состояние, в котором он был до последнего изменения. Мой ответ отметите как правильный И зададите новый вопрос, куда вы прикрепите код, так же не нужно прикреплять картинку тк в ней 0 полезной информации. Просто напишите, что решение не проходит тесты Подробно объясните идею своего решения, ваши мысли и тд Разумеется условие написать. А так же если это возможно, прикрепить ссылку на проверяющую систему. То есть ссылку на сайт, куда вы отправляете решения.